# Storing Variables in Database class

Tags: php

I am new to Php OOP and have written some code for storing some product in a database using PHP OOP. I am tring to store my username and password in a session variable in my database class. Here is my code for my database class as well as what I have for my login form. I am getting the following error when I run it.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_SESSION' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\wdv341\php-oop-crud-level-3\config\database.php on line 9

database.php

```
<?php


class Database{

    // specify your own database credentials
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $db_name = "wdv341";
    private $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    private $password = $_SESSION['password'];
    public $conn;

    // get the database connection
    public function getConnection(){

        $this->conn = null;

        try{
            $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
        }catch(PDOException $exception){
            echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
        }

        return $this->conn;
    }



}
```

?>

userLogin.php

```
<?php
session_cache_limiter('none');          //This prevents a Chrome error when using the back button to return to this page.
session_start();


if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) //This is a valid user.  Show them the Administrator Page
    {

$_SESSION['username']=$_POST['username'];   //pull the username from the form
$_SESSION['password']=$_POST['password'];

//var_dump($_SESSION);

include_once 'config/database.php';

 if (isset($_SESSION['username']) && ($_SESSION['password'])){

header("location:read_categories.php");

}

else
{
?>
<html>
<body>
                <h2>Please login to the Administrator System</h2>
                <form method="post" name="loginForm" action="userLogin.php" >
                  <p>Username: <input name="username" type="text" /></p>
                  <p>Password: <input name="password" type="password" /></p>
                  <p><input name="submitLogin" value="Login" type="submit" /> <input name="" type="reset" />&nbsp;</p>
                </form>
</body>  
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

Please Help!!

Answer (score 1):

The error means it ran into `$_SESSION[]` on line 9, which I assume is roughly here:

```
private $username = $_SESSION['username'];
```

You can't reference `$_SESSION` at this point. [From the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

> ... This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time **and must not depend on run-time information** in order to be evaluated.

You can use a [constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) to set that value when an instance of the class is created instead:

```
class Database {
    private $username;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->username = $_SESSION['username'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much that was the fix!!